# Multiple ip's for same domain

Tags: dns, ip, cross-domain

We have an MS SQL Server database on server with an IP (IP1) and a backup copy of this database with another IP (IP2).

Because of some circumstances first server may be broken and during that time we have to use backup copy.

My collegues offer just to write a windows service that pings first IP every minute and if it isn't accessible, replaces record in **hosts** file with second ip.

I guess, that it has to be more safe and cross-platform solution (like a proxy and stuff) because this problem has to be researched and solved a lot of times and architecture they offer is too fragile and platform-dependent (it depends on OS Windows, you need admin rights to edit hosts, etc).

Is there any "standard" salvation for domain substitute problem?

Comment: it will be more help if you provide which web server you are using

Comment: It's not web, but MS SQL Server.